# Stop timer on cell swipe, but restart when cancelling cell swipe

Tags: swift, timer, tableview

I have a Timer that updates the visible rows of a table view every second. When I swipe the table view cell (to perform a delete action), I stop the timer by using the invalidate method in the editActionsForRowAt function.

What I want is to restart the timer as soon as I tap outside to cancel the cell swipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I guess you can restart your timer inside this method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath?) {
    // restartTimer
}
```